# Minimum number of hemispheres covering a sphere

Tags: geometry, induction, combinatorial-geometry

Here is a question which seems easy but seems to have many pitfalls. If I give you an arbitrary covering of the sphere by $N$ closed hemispheres. You can pick any of the hemispheres to keep. What is the minimum number you can keep while still covering the sphere? We suspect the answer is $4$ but we can't seem to prove it.

Comment: I'm wondering - what is the background / motivation behind this question?

Comment: What ensures that the $4$ hemispheres you keep actually cover the sphere?

Comment: @EnjoysMath the goal is to pick the least amount such that they do, and this question asks whether four are always sufficient.

Comment: @Jan A professor thought that it should be solvable by 7th graders learning induction.

Comment: I was wondering whether Robert Israel's beautiful idea (+1) might be extended to infinite coverings. It turns out it cannot: pick an axis of rotation. This axis intersects the sphere in precisely two points. Now choose the first hemisphere $H_1$ to contain both of these points. Construct the next hemisphere $H_2$ by rotating $H_1$ around the axis by $\frac{\pi}2$. Then construct $H_3$ by rotating $H_2$ by a further $\frac{\pi}4$. Then $H_4$ by rotating $H_3$ by $\frac{\pi}8$. Continuing this process, each time halving the angle, yields an infinite covering with no finite subcovering.

Comment: Your professor has a very high opinion of 7th graders.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that you are talking about a $2$-dimensional sphere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Look up Helly's theorem.

EDIT: I should have been more specific, since Helly had more than one theorem.
The one I'm talking about is the one found at 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem
If your closed hemispheres are $H_1, \ldots, H_n$ (in the sphere $S$), let $X_i$ be the convex hull of $S \backslash H_i$.
 If no $4$ of your hemispheres cover the whole sphere, that says every $4$ of the $X_i$ have nonempty intersection, and then (since
we're in ${\mathbb R}^3$) Helly says the intersection of all the $X_i$ is nonempty, and that implies that $H_i$ don't cover the whole sphere.

Comment: I don't understand how to apply Helly's theorem in this case. Are we somehow relating coverings of the sphere to coverings of the disk? Even then I'm not sure how Helly's theorem applies.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.