# Proving that if $n$ hemispheres cover a sphere, it is possible to choose 4 hemisphere that also cover the sphere.

Tags: geometry, induction, spheres, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

The question is taken from [Cool Induction Problems](https://circles.math.ucla.edu/circles/lib/data/Handout-142-159.pdf).

Quoting:

> (**) A sphere is covered with some number of “caps” which are hemispheres. Prove
> that it is possible to choose four hemispheres, and remove all others, while still keeping
> the sphere covered. (Hint: Sometimes it is easier to prove a more general statement
> than the one given.)

How should I proceed with induction? I tried assuming that the statement is true for $k$ and proving that it is true for $k+1$, but this requires proving an another strong statement that would finish the proof: For $k+1$ caps covering the sphere, you can find $k$ that also cover the sphere for $k\geq 4$. How should I work on proving this statement, or should I work on a different statement?

Also, how does this generalize to $n$-spheres, and even more generally, arbitrary sets of points? (Some places mentioned Helly’s theorem.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Helly's theorem can be applied here, and it's proof is by induction.

Comment: You can generalize the argument given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541185/minimum-number-of-hemispheres-covering-a-sphere).

Comment: Can you give a proof without using Helly's theorem?